# Unfollowed celebrities Facebook accounts and want to reverse it

Tags: facebook, follow

I accidentally unfollowed a bunch of celebrities' Facebook accounts and want to reverse it in an easy way as there were too many profiles to remember.

I can't remember all of the celebs I was following and want to find an easy way to follow them all again, or just find out who I was following so I can follow them again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Activity Log in your facebook account and then use the Filter option and filter by "Following". Hopefully it will show you the list of people you followed.  I have tried this in the facebook android app, should be the same feature in other platform apps and also browser.